# Apple streaming tools on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, video-streaming

Can you guys help me. I need to run Apple's http live streaming command line tools on Linux. I've tried different ways to install .dmg itself, then I've tried to extract files from it, then finally I mounted the .dmg on a Mac machine and copied its content (.pkg) to my Ubuntu. Now I'm stuck, nothing opens the ,pkg. Can you please, please help me.

Maybe there's anyone who familiar with those tools. Only a week ago you could download them from connect.apple.com. Today I found that for some reason Apple removed them. I need to run them on a Linux machine. It's not like totally impossible, right?

Comment: Why do you think these tools would just run on a Linux machine? If they're compiled for OS X, they just won't run on some Linux. So you'd need to get the source code anyway, not a Disk Image or Package.

Comment: Uhm. `[citation needed]`. Do you even know Apple's [open source releases](http://opensource.apple.com/)? (And seriously, don't swear please.)

Comment: Sorry didn't mean any disrespect. It's just driving me crazy.. I need to do segmenting on other (non-Mac) machine and can't find any good solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run Mac OS X executable on Linux OS.

See explanation here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/what-makes-osx-programs-not-runnable-on-linux